# insert data from text file into mysql db white php

Tags: php, mysqli

i tried this code but i dont work

```
    <?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_insert_txt");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
else{
echo "rak connecté";
}
$lines = file('test.txt');  
$test = "";  
$insert_string = "INSERT INTO `test_txt`(`test`) VALUES"; 
$counter = 0; 
$maxsize = count($lines); 
foreach($lines as $line => $company) { 
$insert_string .= "('".$company."')"; 
$counter++; 
if($counter < $maxsize){ 
$insert_string .= ","; 
}//if 
}//foreach 
mysqli_query($insert_string) or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

It gives me the following warning:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message describes pretty well what's wrong.

You need to pass the DB connection parameter to the query:

```
mysqli_query($con, $insert_string);
```

Use it for the following also:

```
mysqli_error($con);
```

Comment: it says no Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\wamp\www\update-from-txt\index.php on line 26

Comment: @HamaneelMehdi you refuse to do any thinking of your own, that's not nice.

Comment: sorry i wont do it agan :/

Comment: @HamaneelMehdi you don't need to apologize to me, it's bad for you not me.